# Gstreamer and motion detection

Tags: command-line-interface, gstreamer

I would like to use gstreamer to store a video when motion is detected but I
don't know how to configure the sink to store the images **only** if a motion
is detected.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! motioncells ! ???
```

I don't care about the cells themselves. Actually, I would rather not have them
rendered on the stored file.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an gst application, register to de bus and when motion was detected enable video record.